# connectionStrings from Multiple files App.config

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I'm need to read connectionStrings from different files .config

```
            file1.ddl.config
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <configuration>
            <connectionStrings>
            <add name="" connectionString=""/>
            </connectionStrings>
            </configuration>

                file2.ddl.config
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <configuration>
            <connectionStrings>
            <add name="" connectionString=""/>
            </connectionStrings>
            </configuration>
```

I try  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NAME"].ConnectionString but i recive "Object not set" and i can't use ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings because it´s deprecated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrGWV.png)

Comment: Have a look at the overview of how configuration works in ASP.Net - you can create your own JSON file provider -see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#json-configuration-provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try add the key's in the same file.

string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; //exePath

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;

string connectionFile = section.ConnectionStrings["nameConnection"].ConnectionString;

Comment: Please show code samples as text formatted as code